# Generating Image in Winform from MS Chart

Tags: c#, winforms, image, charts

I have generated a Piechart using MS chart Library.Now as per my requirement i have to generate a image of this chart and later use this image in my application.Here at present i am generating image through hard coded image name and path Which i dont Want to do.I want image to be generated and saved into Some Variable which i will use later in my application.

Here is my code in c# to generate image..

```
pieChart.SaveImage(@"D:\MyImage.jpg", System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Please help me .
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a Bitmap variable

```
Private Bitmap chartImage;
```

Save the chart to memory stream and then create a bitmap with the memory stream.

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    pieChart.SaveImage(ms, ChartImageFormat.Jpeg);
    this.chartImage= new Bitmap(ms);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The base `Chart` class has the [`DrawToBitmap()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

In case your chart is too big, catch the exception and use a temporary file with `System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();`.